# SVG getPointAtLength() returns invalid coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an svg path and I want to get an actual coordinates of the path with the help of `getPointAtLength(n)` method.

```
var  path = document.getElementById("path1");
var  pathLen = path.getTotalLength();

alert(pathLen);

var posMin = path.getPointAtLength(0);
var posMid = path.getPointAtLength(Math.ceil(pathLen / 2));
var posMax = path.getPointAtLength(pathLen);

alert(posMin.x + ', ' + posMin.y);
alert(posMid.x + ', ' + posMid.y);
alert(posMax.x + ', ' + posMax.y);
```

But it returns strange values.
What I do wrong? I expect to have a positive & normal values of path, for example at start, middle and end of my svg path.

Here is a sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/9xLc6q3n/9/

box should be in the middle of the path

Comment: What browser gives you negative values? On both chrome and FF I get (toFixed2) length: 15881.26
start: 186.03, 4529.87
middle: 259.80, 0.53
end: 186.03, 4529.87

Comment: @Kaiido however `middle: 259.80, 0.53` isn't a valid value. It's a middle of the path, and X==259 - could be ok, but Y definitely not )

Comment: @Kaiido https://jsfiddle.net/9xLc6q3n/9/  this box should be in the middle of path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your box **is** in the middle of your path.  Your path starts at the bottom, runs up to the top, then goes back down to the bottom again.  So the half way point on your path, is at the top of the shape.

Comment: hm... how do you understood this?)

Comment: i created this path in InkScape... and it looks like path from top to bottom

Comment: If it was a single unclosed path, then using `fill` to colour it wouldn't work.  If you open it in Inkscape, zoom in, and select the node tool (F2), you will see what I mean.  I suspect you either used the calligraphic pen, or perhaps you used the "Stroke to path" function.